# android, google map api v2 error

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I am trying to develop one app for Google map v2. i followed the all the instructions. i generate API_KEY and placed it into android manifest file also.
On the "Order and Export" tab I checked "Android Private Libraries" on my project. I also did this for the library project it references.
But i get the error when i run app in emulator as well as android device also. my log cat fallow the error like

```
10-09 03:02:37.905: E/PAUSE(2949): TIMERS!
10-09 03:02:37.921: W/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap;)
10-09 03:02:37.921: I/dalvikvm(2949): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.zarrin.negar.LocationActivity.checkGooglePlayServicesForUpdate
10-09 03:02:37.921: W/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3699: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Landroid/content/Context;)I
10-09 03:02:37.925: D/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0005
10-09 03:02:37.925: E/dalvikvm(2949): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from method com.zarrin.negar.LocationActivity.initialization
10-09 03:02:37.925: W/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 615 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;) in Lcom/zarrin/negar/LocationActivity;
10-09 03:02:37.933: D/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0021
10-09 03:02:37.937: E/dalvikvm(2949): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng', referenced from method com.zarrin.negar.LocationActivity.setGps
10-09 03:02:37.941: W/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 618 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng;) in Lcom/zarrin/negar/LocationActivity;
10-09 03:02:37.941: D/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0021
10-09 03:02:37.941: E/dalvikvm(2949): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng', referenced from method com.zarrin.negar.LocationActivity.setLocation
10-09 03:02:37.945: W/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 618 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng;) in Lcom/zarrin/negar/LocationActivity;
10-09 03:02:37.945: D/dalvikvm(2949): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x001e
10-09 03:02:37.949: D/dalvikvm(2949): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0f0e at 0x27 in Lcom/zarrin/negar/LocationActivity;.setGps
10-09 03:02:37.949: D/dalvikvm(2949): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0f10 at 0x37 in Lcom/zarrin/negar/LocationActivity;.setGps
10-09 03:02:37.949: D/dalvikvm(2949): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0f0e at 0x40 in Lcom/zarrin/negar/LocationActivity;.setGps
10-09 03:02:37.949: I/dalvikvm(2949): Failed resolving Lcom/zarrin/negar/LocationActivity$1; interface 612 'Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap$OnMapClickListener;'
```

manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<permission
    android:name="com.zarrin.negar.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.zarrin.negar.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.zarrin.negar.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.zarrin.negar.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and my activity :

```
<activity
        android:name="com.zarrin.negar.LocationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    </activity>
```

meta data :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my_api_key" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

image of my project's properties :

[image 1](http://cubeupload.com/im/CwtPyi.png)

[image 2](http://cubeupload.com/im/4E5sVX.png)

Comment: update your question with manifest entries please. I suspect a build issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of your project configuration, or your emulator configuration.

Project

- Have you imported as a library Google Play services project from your
  SDK?

Emulator

- Has your emulator installed Google Play Services? Try running an
  emulator with SDK (Google APIs)

Good luck buddy!

Comment: yes,I imported google_play_services_lib as library project , also added these jar files as a Library from google_play_services_lib : 
1.google_play_services.jar
2.google_play_services_lib.jar

this problem doesn't be from emulator because i installed google play service in emulator , also i installed my app to my phone (HTC ONE) but doesn't work again !  :(

Comment: Try updating your SDK. In this desperately situation, please, uninstall your SDK and install it again. In one situation this was the only way to fix a problem I had.